# How do I install Jalmus?

Tags: software

I am trying to install this music reading software: http://www.jalmus.net/Download.html

I downloaded it and double clicked on it and went through the installer. Now there's a file in my Applications folder (OS X) with a bunch of folders in it but no application to run. What else do I need to do?
[image: My applications]

Comment: What is in `bin`?

Comment: Also, according to the instructions on the website you need to start it from Terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is probably in `.../bin`. You can either start it from there or (according to the instructions on the Jalmus website) from the commandline.